# Tensorflow multi gpu example error: Variable conv1/weights/ExponentialMovingAverage/ does not exist

Tags: python, tensorflow, multi-gpu

I am running the code mentioned in this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn/

I downloaded the code from here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/

I am running the code on a g2.4xlarge machine in AWS on ubuntu 14.04. The single gpu example runs fine without any errors.

Can someone help how to fix this? I am running 0.12 version.

---

ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx:~/pythonworkspace/tensorflowdev/models-master/tutorials/image/cifar10$ python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.**version**)'

### 0.12.head

ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx:~/pythonworkspace/tensorflowdev/models-master/tutorials/image/cifar10$ python cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py --num_gpus=2

```
>> Downloading cifar-10-binary.tar.gz 100.0%
Successfully downloaded cifar-10-binary.tar.gz 170052171 bytes.
Filling queue with 20000 CIFAR images before starting to train. This will take a few minutes.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/ubuntu/pythonworkspace/tensorflowdev/models-master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py:135: image_summary (from tensorflow.python.ops.logging_ops) is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-11-30.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.summary.image. Note that tf.summary.image uses the node name instead of the tag. This means that TensorFlow will automatically de-duplicate summary names based on the scope they are created in. Also, the max_images argument was renamed to max_outputs.
Filling queue with 20000 CIFAR images before starting to train. This will take a few minutes.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/ubuntu/pythonworkspace/tensorflowdev/models-master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py:135: image_summary (from tensorflow.python.ops.logging_ops) is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-11-30.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.summary.image. Note that tf.summary.image uses the node name instead of the tag. This means that TensorFlow will automatically de-duplicate summary names based on the scope they are created in. Also, the max_images argument was renamed to max_outputs.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py", line 273, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py", line 269, in main
    train()
  File "cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py", line 210, in train
    variables_averages_op = variable_averages.apply(tf.trainable_variables())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/moving_averages.py", line 373, in apply
    colocate_with_primary=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/slot_creator.py", line 110, in create_slot
    return _create_slot_var(primary, val, "")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/slot_creator.py", line 64, in _create_slot_var
    use_resource=_is_resource(primary))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1034, in get_variable
    use_resource=use_resource, custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 933, in get_variable
    use_resource=use_resource, custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 356, in get_variable
    validate_shape=validate_shape, use_resource=use_resource)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 341, in _true_getter
    use_resource=use_resource)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 671, in _get_single_variable
    "VarScope?" % name)
ValueError: Variable conv1/weights/ExponentialMovingAverage/ does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can find the answer to your problem here:
[Issue 6220](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6220)

You need to put:
`with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope())`
in front of the loop which runs over your devices ...

so, do that:

```
with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope()):
    for i in xrange(FLAGS.num_gpus):
        with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
```

The explanation is given in the link...
Here the quote:

> When you do tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables() you set the
>   current scope to reuse variables. If you call the optimizer in such
>   scope, it's trying to reuse slot variables, which it cannot find, so
>   it throws an error. If you put a scope around, the
>   tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables() only affects that scope, so
>   when you exit it, you're back in the non-reusing mode, the one you
>   want.
>
> Hope that helps, let me know if I should clarify more.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That fixed it.